# Linux Command to display only mingetty's info

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I am looking for a command that will give only mingetty's information. How can you construct the command to find only mingetty data and find the PPID in Linux?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-C` option to select processes by name, and `-o` to specify the output information.

```
ps -C mingetty -o ppid
```